# Excel - Condition of my IF Statement not returning the correct result

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Can someone understand why my IF Statement isn't returning the desired result? The logic makes sense to me but obviously it is incorrect.

What I'm trying to do is make A1 = B1 if both C1 and D1 are blank. This condition of my IF Statement isn't working, it returns a 0. Does anyone know why?

What I think the logic of my IF Statement is AND what I'm trying to achieve:

IF D1 is blank, make the content of A1 = C1. IF C1 is blank, make the content of A1 = B1. Otherwise make A1 = D1.

```html
=IF(ISBLANK(D1),C1,IF(ISBLANK(C1),B1,D1))
```

Comment: `If` function stops executing after the first section where `logical_test=TRUE`. So if `D1` is blank, result will be `c1` no matter what is in `C1`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you so much for the insight. I flipped my ISBLANK functions and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

So check C1 & D1 and set A1 = B1, enter this in cell A1:

=if(and(C1="",D1=""),B1,D1)

This will set cell A1 equal to B1 if C1 & D1 are blank, if either C1 or D1 are not blank then A1 will be equal to D1.

This is based on your middle paragraph:
*What I'm trying to do is make A1 = B1 if both C1 and D1 are blank*.

What you have in your final paragraph is different:
*IF D1 is blank, make the content of A1 = C1. IF C1 is blank, make the content of A1 = B1. Otherwise make A1 = D1.*
As you don't test C1 and D1 together.

Edit based on your comment:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(C1),ISBLANK(D1)),B1,if(isblank(D1),C1,D1))
```

Which does if both C1&D1 are blank then B1, if D1 is blank then C1 if not B1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm looking to achieve the logic in my final paragraph. I didn't realize I had to test C1 and D1 together so that was a big help. Now I just need to figure out how to do that. I tried using the AND function you used, but got the same issue. The second ISBLANK works on its own but not while nested. "=IF(ISBLANK(D1),C1,IF(AND(ISBLANK(C1),ISBLANK(D1)),B1,D1))"

Comment: @Wolk your last expression will only get to the second if() when D1 is blank, but you will never get the result B1, as if D1 is blank it will be trapped by the first if().

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight. I flipped my ISBLANK functions and it worked.